# Using a string in place of an object when accessing it

Tags: c#, object, charts

First off I'm sure that I am using the wrong terminology here but I will fix it if someone comments on it. Please be gentle.

So I have multiple `charts` on a page and I am performing virtually identical actions on each. For demonstrative purposes lets call my `charts` something like: `chart1`, `chart2`, ..., `chartn` where *n* is somewhere in the vicinity of 20. What I would like to do is drop this in a `for` loop and perform all the work in one smaller chunk of code, especially if I have to tweak it later.

So my question is whether or not I can vary the *n* part representing the object (terminology?) so I can get this done more efficiently.

i.e.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    String chartName = "chart" + i;
    chartName.Series.Clear();
}
```

I have a feeling you can't do this with a string so I was looking into doing a `foreach` but I don't know how to do this with charts.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm really not sure what the question is here. Can you try and provide some more information?

Comment: Your really should use array/list/collection of objects... But take a look at my previous answer to similar question if you really need unique variables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424570/c-sharp-how-to-treat-ints-like-they-are-array/15424657#15424657

Comment: I'm guessing you have variables named `chart1`, `chart2`, etc.. and you want to loop through them? And your idea was: if I could build the name `"chart1"` somehow as a string, and resolve that to the actual `chart1` variable, then I can work with it. Right?

Comment: Oops, Virtlink has already given you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the charts in a list. For example, this makes a list of `Chart` objects (or whatever your chart type is):

```
List<Chart> charts = new List<Chart>();
```

Then you can add charts:

```
charts.Add(new Chart());
```

And use them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charts.Count; i++)
{
    charts[i].Series.Clear();
}
```

Of course, you can make the `charts` variable a field in your class.

---

You can directly initialize a list (or array, or dictionary<sup>1</sup>) like this:

```
List<Chart> charts = new List<Charts>()
{
    new Chart(),
    new Chart(),
    existingChart1,
    existingChart2
};
```

Or, if you create a new array of objects using that syntax...

```
Chart[] arrayOfCharts = new []
{
    new Chart(),
    new Chart(),
    existingChart1,
    existingChart2
};
```

...then you can add multiple objects at once using `AddRange`:

```
charts.AddRange(arrayOfCharts);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>) You can use this so-called *collection initializer* syntax on any object that has a public `Add` method.

Comment: While I`m at it, I am curious about something (I don`t really need it here). Can you add multiple objects to a list at once? i.e. `charts.Add(chart1, chart2, chart3)` or something like this? I know what I just wrote doesn't work, but is there another way? Sort of like declaring several variables at once. Thanks!

Comment: `charts.AddRange(new [] {chart1, chart2, chart3 })` will allow you to add a number of chart objects to the charts list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your chart from a list/array/collection  of charts like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
  String chartName = "chart" + i;
  Charts(chartName).Series.Clear();
}
```

or maybe

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
  String chartName = "chart" + i;
  Charts(i).Series.Clear();
}
```