# C# List of references to another list elements

Tags: c#, list, reference

I want to build a sublist with references to the elements of anoter list (i need few of them, that are meeting the conditions).

How am i trying to do that:

```
        List<int> mainList = new List<int>();
        List<int> subList = new List<int>();
        mainList.Add(5);
        subList.Add(mainList[0]); //case 1
        //subList[0] = mainList[0]; //case 2
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0]);
        subList[0]++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0]);
        mainList[0]+=2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0]);
```

In the first case i'm getting the copy instead of reference because the console output is:

```
5
5
5
6
7
6
```

In the second case i'm getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException because `subList[0]` is not initialized.
So, how can i do this?

Also, according to speed/memory usage may be it's even better to keep `List<int>` of inedexes of the mainList instead of references?

Comment: Why are you worried about the performance of code that does not work correctly?

Comment: @AluanHaddad because there may be few correct solutions in my case, so i'm going to check which is better as well.

Comment: This would work if you wrap your int in a class. Currently you are copying your int on line 4

Comment: Well, I would strongly advise that you not optimize anything until you get it to behave correctly. Doing so leads to madness.

Comment: @AluanHaddad please, don't pay that much attention to the last 
paragraph of the question, it's not exactly about the main problem, it's just an additional thoughts.

Comment: @slawekwin in my case, list items wouldn't be swapped or deleted, so it's pretty safe. but 1st of all i want to know if it's possible to build such reference

Comment: @ManIkWeet can you please explane a bit more about "wrap you int" in this case

Comment: You can't build a reference to an int like that. Int is not an object type but a primary type.

Comment: @Florian sounds like a 1st good explanation, thank you

Comment: I've found this that may be helping you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985646/how-to-store-a-reference-to-an-integer-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ManIkWeet and @Florian, i've found the solution:

```
        public class TestClass{
           public int value;
        }

        ...

        List<TestClass> mainList = new List<TestClass>();
        List<TestClass> subList = new List<TestClass>();
        mainList.Add(new TestClass { value = 5 });
        subList.Add(mainList[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0].value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0].value);
        subList[0].value++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0].value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0].value);
        mainList[0].value+=2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mainList[0].value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subList[0].value);
```

Output is:

```
5
5
6
6
8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 2: You can not assign the value in list when list is not containing any element because there is no memory allocalted to your list items in sublist.

you are getting the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException because your list index is less than 0 or index is equal to or greater than list count

You can assign value via indexing when you have item in your list

Hope this help !