# Is there a concise way in C# to (based on logic) allocate one reference or another?

Tags: c#, reference

<sub>[Sorry about the clumsy title - I couldn't figure out the best way to express what I am trying to do.]</sub>

I feel a bit silly - I just discovered a bug in the following code of mine:

```
private static XmlSchemaSet internalSchema = null;
private static XmlSchemaSet externalSchema = null;
private static XmlSchemaSet GetSchema(SchemaType schemaType)
{
    // Lazy evaluation of schema objects - only create internal
    // and external schema once
    XmlSchemaSet schema =
        schemaType == SchemaType.Internal ? internalSchema : externalSchema;
    if (schema == null)
    {
        schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schema.Add("", CreateXmlSchemaFile(schemaType));
    }
    return schema;
}
```

The intent of the code is to allocate the static members `internalSchema` and `externalSchema` only once, when they are first requested.

Of course there's an obvious bug with my attempted concise code - the `schema` local reference is pointing to the *object* that `internalSchema` or `externalSchema` is pointing to (`null` initially), but as soon as I call `new`, it only reassigns the *local* reference, not the static member.

Is there a easy way to achieve what I am trying to do?  I guess I could create another method which takes an `XmlSchemaSet` via the `ref` keyword, but it seems silly to create another method just for this.

Comment: you can choose which field to set using a ref parameter: `if (condition) Set (ref fieldA); else Set (ref fieldB);` but since C# doesn't support ref locals, you can't assign the reference based on a condition and have a single call site for the method.

Comment: Eric Lippert has written a few times about implementing a prototype C# with the ref local feature; if I recall correctly, he has done it, but there has been no compelling use case identified that would justify adding the feature to the actual product.

Comment: @phoog - thanks.  My initial thoughts when asking this question was whether there was such thing as a ref local, and my original question was going to ask this more explicitly.

Comment: Related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542536/is-it-possible-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-in-c/4543089#4543089, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284767/can-i-use-a-reference-inside-a-c-sharp-function-like-c/3285002#3285002

Comment: Also see Eric Lippert's blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx

Comment: Thanks for finding that link -- I didn't have time to do so when I posted those comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to assign "reference to a reference type" to a local variable the way you're asking; using a `ref` parameter to a method is the only direct way to accomplish it.

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use the `Lazy<>` class to do the lazy initialization the way you want, which (IMO) can make your code easier to read by removing the one-time initialization code from the common-case access code, e.g.:

```
private static Lazy<XmlSchemaSet> internalSchema = new Lazy<XmlSchemaSet>(() => CreateSchema(SchemaType.Internal));
private static Lazy<XmlSchemaSet> externalSchema = new Lazy<XmlSchemaSet>(() => CreateSchema(SchemaType.External));

private static XmlSchemaSet CreateSchema(SchemaType schemaType)
{
    var schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schema.Add("", CreateXmlSchemaFile(schemaType));
    return schema;
}

private static XmlSchemaSet GetSchema(SchemaType schemaType)
{
    return schemaType == SchemaType.Internal 
      ? internalSchema.Value 
      : externalSchema.Value;
}
```

Otherwise, I would suggest you not try to be too fancy, and just write your code to do exactly what you want. "Correct" code trumps "concise" code 100% of the time:

```
if (schemaType == SchemaType.Internal)
{ 
    if (internalSchema == null)
    {
        internalSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        internalSchema.Add("", CreateXmlSchemaFile(schemaType));
    }
    return internalSchema;
}
else
{
    if (externalSchema == null)
    {
        externalSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        externalSchema.Add("", CreateXmlSchemaFile(schemaType));
    }
    return externalSchema;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class is what you are looking for.

Approximate usage:

```
private static Lazy<XmlSchemaSet> internalSchema = new Lazy<XmlSchemaSet>(
  () => {
   schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
   schema.Add("", CreateXmlSchemaFile(SchemaType.Internal));
   return schema;
  });
```

Comment: I will check out the documentation, but would it be straight-forward to parametrize the `Lazy<T>` constructor to allow it to create the external or internal schema as appropriate?

Comment: I've updated sample to use enum value (still have not checked if it compiles...)