# Generalize an algorithm that needs to work on different data members

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that is like this:

```
void someAlgorithm(SomeType someVar)
{
  someVar.someMember = createSomeValue();
  lock(something)
  {
    SomeType someOtherVar = something.Find(someVar.unrelatedMember);
    if(someOtherVar != null)
      someOtherVar.someMember = someVar.someMember;
  }
}
```

(I needed to adapt it a bit for posting, so please bear with me if I messed it up in doing so.)

Now I need this exact piece of code for ***another member*** of `someVar` (which has a related, but different type) and ***another creation function***. I know I can just take this code, copy it, replace a few identifiers, and be done. But I feel dirty doing so. I feel there should be a way to generalize this little algorithm.

I know I can always pass the creation function as a delegate, but I don't know how to generalize the member access and then there's the issue of those members (and creation functions) having different types.

In C++, I would use member pointers combined with templates for doing this. Member pointers aren't exactly a piece of cake to use, but once I had looked up their weird syntax, I'd be done within a few minutes. How to do that in C#?

***Edit:*** Since this doesn't seem clear enough, here's what that other instance of the same algorithm looks like:

```
void someOtherAlgorithm(SomeOtherType someVar) // 1 change here
{
  someVar.someOtherMember = createSomeOtherValue(); // 2 changes here
  lock(something)
  {
    SomeOtherType someOtherVar = something.Find(someVar.unrelatedMember);
    if(someOtherVar != null)
      someOtherVar.someOtherMember = someVar.someOtherMember; // 2 changes here
  }
}
```

I hope this clarifies this.

Comment: And the method body is exactly the same?

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes, except that all uses of `someMember` are replaced by `someOtherMember` and `createSomeValue()` by `createSomeOtherValue()`.

Comment: Is `someOtherVar` the same type as `someVar`?

Comment: @SLaks: "...which has a related, but different type..."

Comment: You may find the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980463/how-do-i-assign-by-reference-to-a-class-field-in-c/2982037#2982037 to be relevant to your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confused me a bit, there. Your `someAlgorithm` takes a parameter of type `SomeType` called `someOtherVar` and declares a local variable with the same name (so it can't compile as is). From your two definitions it appears that `someVar` and `someOtherVar` are the same type (`SomeType`), but your local variable is only declared with `var`, so it isn't entirely clear whether they are or not.

In your comment to SLaks you imply that `someVar` and `someOtherVar` are of different types (even though in the part of your question that you quoted you were talking about different members of `someVar` while SLaks was asking about your two variables `someVar` and `someOtherVar`). So I'm going to assume they're different types and that `someOtherVar` is only a local variable, not a parameter.

Based on these assumptions:

```
void someAlgorithm<TMember>(
    SomeType someVar,
    Func<TMember> create,                   // replaces "createSomeValue"
    Func<SomeType, TMember> getter,         // replaces get for "someMember"
    Action<SomeType, TMember> setter,       // replaces set for "someMember"
    Action<SomeOtherType, TMember> setter2) // replaces set for "someMember"
                                            // on "someOtherVar" (not necessary
                                            // if "someOtherVar" is actually
                                            // the same type as "someVar")
{
  setter(somevar, create());

  lock(something)
  {
    SomeOtherType someOtherVar = something.Find(someVar.unrelatedMember);

    if(someOtherVar != null)
      setter2(someOtherVar, getter(someVar));
  }
}
```

For your first algorithm, this would be called like:

```
someAlgorithm(
    someVar,
    createSomeValue,
    x => x.someMember,
    (x, y) => { x.someMember = y; },
    (x, y) => { x.someMemberOfOtherType = y; }
);
```

For your second:

```
someAlgorithm(
    someVar,
    createSomeOtherValue,
    x => x.someOtherMember,
    (x, y) => { x.someOtherMember = y; },
    (x, y) => { x.someOtherMemberOfOtherType = y; }
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I suspected I messed up when I tried to extract that algorithm, but, of course, I didn't see it... Anyway, thanks for your effort in (rightly) deducing what I needed. It seems you have found the way to do what I wanted (`+1` from me for that), although it is as I feared: it's almost easier to maintain the copied code than that. `:(` Well, as of now the algorithm has considerably grown, and there's two more with the very same problem, so it seems this is worth the effort anyway.

Comment: @sbi: On the maintainability of this code: I agree, all of these delegates can quickly become very cumbersome. For this reason I would recommend possibly defining some *interface* that can deal with the different objects in this algorithm the way you want. This way instead of accepting a `SomeType` and 4 (!) delegates, your algorithm can accept a `SomeType` and an instance of an interface that provides 4 analogous methods.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is to use a `Func` delegate and pass a simple selector function as an argument to the algorithm. You can make the method generic, so that the selector can return members of any type:

```
void someAlgorithm<T>(SomeType someVar, SomeType someOtherVar, 
                      Func<SomeType, T> selector) { 
  someVar.someMember = createSomeValue(); 
  lock(something) { 
    var someOtherVar = something.Find(selector(someVar));  // Use 'selector'
    if(someOtherVar != null) 
      someOtherVar.someMember = someVar.someMember; 
  } 
}
```

Then you can write something like:

```
someAlgorithm(some1, some2, a => a.SomeOtherMember);
```

Without more details about your actual code, it is a bit difficult to write the answer precisely (e.g. you may need some constraints for the generic type parameter - e.g. `IComparable` if you're comparing the values), but this is generally the best approach to solving the problem.

If you need another parameterization in the code that sets/gets values of `someMember` then you would just add other functions. For example `Action<SomeType, T>` (which sets value) and one more "selector" function for the other member. In the call, this would be `(s, val) => s.SomeMember = val`. If `someMember` has a different type, then you'd probably need to add one more type parameter.

Comment: I suggest you add another example how to make the assignment to someMember in a generic manner, too.

Comment: Please read my question again: instead of `someMember` I need `someOtherMember`. Yours doesn't help with this. The algorithm is almost exactly as shown in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass lambda expressions that create and set the values.

For example:

```
void someAlgorithm<TObject, TProperty>(TObject someVar, Func<TProperty> creator, Action<TObject, TProperty> setter, Action<SomeType, TProperty> relatedSetter)
{
  var value = creator();
  setter(someVar, value);
  lock(something)
  {
    var someOtherVar = something.Find(someVar.SomeOtherMember);
    if(someOtherVar != null)
      relatedSetter(someOtherVar, value);
  }
}


someAlgotihm(something, createSomeValue, (x, v) => x.someProperty = v, (x, v) => x.someProperty = v);
```

Comment: Please read my question again. I have added the second instance of the algorithm. I would also need to change the line `someOtherVar.someMember = someVar.someMember;` Passing the lambdas to do that makes that almost unreadable. Also, does this account for the different data members being of different types?

Comment: You can pass another lambda for `someOtherVar` (or reuse the first lambda is the type and property is the same).  The generics allow for different types.

Comment: It seems to me the `someVar.SomeOtherMember` part won't really work when `someVar` can be any arbitrary `TObject` (unless you add a generic constraint forcing `TObject` to derive from some base class).

Comment: @Dan: Correct.  A constraint or additional lamdba will be needed.