# Closure captured variable modifies the original as well

Tags: c#, .net, closures

I have the following simple code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int j = 0;
    Func<int> f = () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            j += i;
        }
        return j;
    };

    int myStr = f();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.Read();
}
```

From what I read when closures are involved, a new type is created by the compiler so it can store the captured variable and maintain a reference to it. However, when I run the following code, both printed lines show 3. I was expecting 0 and 3, because the anonymous method has its own variable in the generated class by the compiler. So why does it also modify the outside variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The outside variable and the variable in the closure are *the same variable*. Your program is equivalent to:

```
private class Closure
{
    public int j;
    public int Method()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            this.j += i;
        }
        return this.j;
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Closure closure = new Closure();
    closure.j = 0;
    Func<int> f = closure.Method;
    int myStr = f();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);
    Console.WriteLine(closure.j);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Now is it clear why you get the observed result?

Comment: Wow, first of all, haven't seen an answer from you for a while. Second, its very clear now, altough i looked at the IL, its somewhat giberish for me. I had no ideea it acts like that.

Comment: Eric, you said this behavior may change in a future release of C#.  I know you and MS said your goodbye's.  However, did this change make it into 5.0 or still think that's gonna happen?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: The behaviour that a lambda captures an outer variable is by design and will never change. However, we did make a change in C# 5: the *loop variable of a foreach* is now logically *inside* the loop body, not logically *outside* the loop body. Therefore every time you close over the loop variable of a foreach you get a *fresh* variable to close over in C# 5.0, not a shared variable as you do in C# 4.0.

Comment: If there were two lambda's in `Main` which closed over the same variables, would the compiler generate a single `Closure` class, but with a separate `Method` for each of the lambdas?  I guess it has to since they're closing over the same variables.

Comment: @TimGoodman: Yes. And in fact if there are two lambdas that close over *different* variables, only one closure is generated! This means that the lifetime of one variable can be extended by a delegate that does not close over it. It's a know shortcoming of C# that hopefully will eventually be addressed.

Comment: @TimGoodman: Jon Skeet and Eric both discuss this closure issue a bit more in answers to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885106/18192).

Answer (score 5):

This is how closures work, they capture variables, not values.  So `j` will be changed.

If you don't want that, you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int j = 0;
    Func<int> f = () =>
    {
        int k = j;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            k += i;
        }
        return k;
    };
    int myStr = f();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.Read();
}
```

`j` is still captured by the closure, but not modified.  Only the copy `k` is modified.

**Edit:**

You correctly note that this won't work for reference types.  In that case `k = j` stores a copy of a reference to an object. There's still one copy of the object *being* referenced, so any modifications to that object will effect both variables.

Here's an example of how you would use the closure for a reference type and not update the original variable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo j = new Foo(0);
    Func<Foo> f = () =>
    {
        Foo k = new Foo(j.N); // Can't just say k = j;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            k.N += 1;
        }
        return k;
    };

    Console.WriteLine(f().N);
    Console.WriteLine(j.N);
    Console.Read();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int N { get; set; }

    public Foo(int n) { N = n; }
}
```

However, strings being *immutable* reference types, you actually *can* just say `k = j`, unlike with arbitrary reference types.  One way to think of the immutability is that every time you update the value of a string, you are actually creating a new instance.  So `k = k + "1"` is like saying `k = new String(k + "1")`.  At that point, it's no longer a reference to the same string as `j`.

Comment: at first it look like very strange behaviour, altough k is a value type, thus its probably a new copy of j, so thats why only k is affected

Comment: does copying the variable offer the same behaviour for reference types?What if j was a string for example.

Comment: You're right that being a value type matters.  For reference types, you have to construct a new object for k (e.g. with the `new` keyword).  If you just say `k = j` they will refer to the same object.  Strings are an exception though, because they're immutable -- essentially every time you update the value of a string, you're actually creating a new instance of the `String` class.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover how things are different for reference types.

Comment: Yes but it still modifies the both... my Env is .NET 4.5 with vs 2012

Comment: When you just use the closure without defining the new variable k, then both are modified (this is true for value types and reference types).  When you define the variable `k = j` within the closure (my first example above), then for value types and immutable reference types like `String` only `k` is changed, not `j`.  For mutable reference types (like `Foo` in my second example), if you want `k` to change and not `j` you can use `new` like in my second example.

Comment: Which is modifying both?  The output of both my examples above is `3` `0`.

Comment: both of them, even if i use int or string both variables are affected. Im doing this just for academic purposes, to understand its behaviour, its not a requirement, but i might encounter it and must know how to handle the situation.

Comment: Your saying you've copied my code exactly and are getting `3` `3` instead of `3` `0`?  I'm not sure I believe it... Please check for copy errors.

Comment: In the case when i use new, then the output is indeed 3 0, but in this case i am no longer using an outside variable, but rather a variable declared wthin the same method that has no reference to the old one. Therefore i am not capturing the outside variable.

Comment: The closure captures the outside variable `j`.  Try changing `j` before calling `f()` to see this, the closure will use the changed value.  However, the point of my examples is to show that you can copy the value of `j` to a new variable `k` within `f()` and that way any updates you make to this new variable won't affect `j`.  This is useful if you want to use a lambda but *not* modify the variable you closed over.

Comment: That is true, thank youfor the examples.i looked in the IL and it seems the new type that holds the outside var is still created, if i am reading this correctly: "newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()"

Answer (score 4):

The language specification says:

> Anonymous methods are similar to lambda functions in the Lisp programming language. C# 2.0 supports the creation of “closures” where anonymous methods access surrounding local variables and parameters.

And 'j' in your case is surrounding variable.