# Why are "DisplayClass" and calling method name ordered this way in the stack trace?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

First of all, I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/57428) and no, it only says *how it is implemented right now*, but doesn't explain why.

Here's a sample program (same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16401860/57428)):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try {
            implMain();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void implMain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            invoke(() => {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            });
        }
    }
    static void invoke(Action what)
    {
        what();
    }
}
```

which outputs the following call stack:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2.<implMain>b__0()
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.invoke(Action what)
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.implMain()
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main()
```

Note these two lines:

```
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2.<implMain>b__0()
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.invoke(Action what)
```

The lower one (with `invoke()`) says that there's namespace `ConsoleApplication1` with class `Program` in it that has member `invoke()`. Here left-to-right corresponds to outer-to-inner.

The upper one (with `c__DisplayClass2`) says again there's a namespace and a class...

and then there's `c__DisplayClass2` which means "a magic name the compiler chosen for storing captured variables" and then there's `<implMain>` as if it is a parameter to `c__DisplayClass2`. So it reads as if `c__DisplayClass2` somehow is part of `Program` and `implMain` is part of `c__DisplayClass2`.

Now as I see it it's logically the opposite - there's `implMain()` method and there's "magic class" `c__DisplayClass2` crafted specifically for `implMain()` local variables. So to me it looks like the upper line should look like this:

```
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.implMain.c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
```

(maybe with some extra symbols to prevent possible conflicts) but I hope my idea is clear - this way it would look like `c__DisplayClass2` is crafted specifically to facilitate `implMain()` functioning.

Is there any reason why the current implementation shows the method name (`implMain`) after the local variables capture class name (`c__DisplayClass2`) and not vice versa?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3885161/335858) may be an interesting read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<implMain>b__0()` is just the name of the method.

Inspection in a disassembler will show you this. The `<` and `>` does not imply generics.

The inclusion of `implMain` probably just hints where the delegate was created.