# Is it legal to assign by ref to a field using IL?

Tags: c#, clr, reflection.emit

There is as far as I know no way to interact with reference types in Expression trees. (e.g. nothing emits a  `stind.*` or a `ldind.*` opcode). 
I'm working on a bit of a rewriter to get around this annoyance. Since I'm building a new type that has the method body replaced with delegate invocations (to get around the fact that `CompileToMethod` can only do static methods that can't interact with new members). For by-ref and out parameters, I thought I'd replace their usages with `StrongBox<T>`.

So if I came across a method that has a signature that looks like this::

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual bool SomeMethod(string arg1,ref int arg2)
    {
    }
}
```

The override, the callbase method, and the delegate field I generate will look like this::

```
public class SomeClass<1> : SomeClass
{
     private static bool SomeMethod<0>(
             SomeClass target,string arg1,StrongBox<int> arg2)
     {
        return call target.SomeMethod(arg1,ref arg2.Value)
     }

     private Func<SomeClass,string,StrongBox<int>,bool> <0>SomeMethod;

    public override bool SomeMethod(string arg1,ref int arg2)
    {
        StrongBox<int> box = new StrongBox<int>();
        box.Value = arg2;
        bool retVal = <0>SomeMethod.Invoke(this,arg1,box);
        arg2 = box.Value;
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

However, this is quite a lot of code to perform this conversion, for each parameter it introduces a lot of complexity. It would be much easier when I perform the setting of `box.Value = arg2`, if I could do something like `&box.Value = &arg2` that is assign it's address to the address of arg2 as it stands. That way when the delegate performs a mutation on the value field the changes are forwarded. Doing this means I don't need to have to have a variable to hold the return value, and I don't need to perform a reference value update.

Alternatively, if there is a way to perform assign-by-ref semantics with Expression trees, I'm all ears of course.

Comment: This makes me think of Eric Lippert's [Ref Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980463/how-do-i-assign-by-reference-to-a-class-field-in-c/2982037#2982037).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand but maybe this is a solution:

```
class Program
{

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private readonly int _n;

        public SomeClass(int n) { _n = n; }

        public virtual bool SomeMethod(string arg1, ref int arg2) {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg1)) return false;
            arg2 += arg1.Length + _n;
            return true;
        }
    }

    private delegate bool SomeDelegate(SomeClass that, string arg1, ref int arg2);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof (SomeClass), "that");
        var arg1Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "arg1");
        var arg2Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int).MakeByRefType(), "arg2");
        var someMethodInfo = typeof (SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<SomeDelegate>(Expression.Call(instance, someMethodInfo, arg1Param, arg2Param), instance, arg1Param, arg2Param);
        var someDelegate =lambda.Compile();
        var myClass = new SomeClass(2);
        var arg1 = "yup";
        var arg2 = 1;
        var result = someDelegate(myClass, arg1, ref arg2);
        if(arg2 != 6) throw new Exception("Bad!");
        Console.WriteLine("works...");
    }

}
```

The important bit I think is `typeof (int).MakeByRefType()` .