# Why for loop is creating variable with the same address?

Tags: c#

Why with this code:

```
unsafe
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Double w = new Double();
            Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)(&w));
        }
    }
```

i'm always getting the same number? How to create new variables in a loop ? With new addresses ?

The reason, why this is a problem for me is that I need to generate a random double number and then I'm using a pointer (which references to that double) in two objects. In one of the object I'm changing this value and I want it to change in that other object too :)

Comment: "`i`" isn't doing anything except incrementing; and you're not doing *anything* with "`w`" except writing (possibly uninitialized) garbage.

Comment: I'm guessing it's some compiler optimization. The compiler can probably tell that you're not doing anything with `w`, so it doesn't create a new instance everytime.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: The second half of your analysis is incorrect. Why would the address be garbage?

Comment: @EricLipper We don't know what value "`w`" is set to.  Maybe zero?  Maybe 23434124231234.  Maybe `0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann he's looking for the memory address of `w`, not the value of `w`

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to **achieve** with this code?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann `Double` is a value type, so sure do we know what value `w` is set to: `0.0`. And even if he was using `w` in whatever way; it would still run out of scope and its address could be reused in the next iteration.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: `new Double()`, `default(double)` and `0.0` are all ways to write the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to **share the reference to the value** of the value type. So, it can be done by **wrapping the value type into the reference type**:

```
class Ref<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Please also see the related question: [C# - Good and flexible way to pass value types by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110187/c-sharp-good-and-flexible-way-to-pass-value-types-by-reference).

Comment: @EricLippert, sure, because the [array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

Logically, that's a new variable every time through the loop. But I hope that you would not expect a new variable to actually be allocated off the stack every time!  What if the loop runs a million times? The compiler knows that it can re-use the storage, and it does.

If you want ten different addresses, make an array with ten elements, fix it in place, and take the address of each element.

Comment: So, if he declared the variable outside the loop and instantiated it inside the loop, would he be getting a new address everytime (since the compiler isn't creating more space on the stack)?

Comment: Yes, "But I hope that you would not expect a new variable to actually be allocated off the stack every time!" this is exactly what I need to do, because I need to generate a random double number and then I'm using a pointer (which references to that double) in two classes. In one of the class I'm changing this value and I want it to change in that other class too :)

Comment: @BenasRadzevicius it sounds like you might be using C# wrong.