# Update reference (`ref`) in a difference method

Tags: c#, interface, pass-by-reference, ref

I am trying to update the variable `ref container` that was passed via constructor to set to equal to a new object in a `Run` method. Of course, in `Run` method I am updating the reference of to `Foo::_container` not the variable `container` that was defined in `Main`. So I am wondering if there is a way to save the container reference that was passed via constructor and subsequently update the value of reference. Thank you.

```
public class Foo
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public Foo(ref IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var temp = new Container();
        _container = temp;
    }
}


static class Main
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IContainer container = null;
        (new Foo(ref container)).Run();

        // container is still null
        Console.WriteLine(container);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you are trying to do. The ref argument is local to the method. Taking a step back, what exactly are you trying to achieve? You aren't keeping `Foo` alive so what is the purpose of attempting to store the `IContainer` reference or having a separate `Run()` method?

Comment: Since you can't have a ref field, the discussion of [why and work arounds in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980463/how-do-i-assign-by-reference-to-a-class-field-in-c) is very relevant.