# How do I shorten the path to a property?

Tags: c#

For example if I have `Object.ObjectTwo.Property` and I don't want to clutter my code by writing that all the time, is there a way to make it shorter?

Instead of writing `Object.ObjectTwo.Property = something`, I would like to be able to write `myVariable = something`.

I couldn't find anything when I tried searching.

Edit: The member in question is a property.

Comment: Maybe just declare a separate variable? ObjectA=Object.ObjectTwo.Variable

Comment: **Is Object.ObjectTwo.Variable actually a variable**?  This is important. C# 7 allows you to make short aliases for *variables*, but not for *properties*.  Local variables, formal parameters, array elements, instance fields, static fields and unsafe pointer dereferences are *variables*.  Properties are not. Which is it? Is `Variable` a field, or a property?

Comment: Second question, are `Object` and `ObjectTwo` of *reference type* or *value type*?

Comment: Also FYI pretty much none of the answers, including the one you marked as correct, are correct.  **There is not enough information in the problem yet to answer the question definitively and marking it as answered was premature**.

Comment: It is a property!

Comment: I was working with Unity. I was working with a line looking like this: camera.backgroundColor.r = 1 and I wanted it to be shortened to bgColor = 1. Where camera is a class, backgroundColor is a struct and r is a float.

Comment: Is *backgroundColor* a property or a variable? Presumably it is a variable, since the code given would not work if it were a property and the value is a struct, since the mutation would be lost. More generally though, mutating a value type like this is considered a poor practice. As this question has aptly pointed out, the semantics of mutating values of struct-valued fields is very tricky!

Answer (score 4):

In **C#**, you can create shorthands for variable types at the global scope (where you put statements like `using System;`).

If you want to shorten `Object.ObjectTwo` to something simpler, you can use a `using` statement in the following manner:

```
using Object.ObjectTwo = ObjTwo;
```

Then, you can later call `ObjTwo.Variable = someVar;`, and it will act as if you had used `Object.ObjectTwo.Variable = someVar;`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just declare a separate variable?

```
var ObjectA = Object.ObjectTwo.Variable;
```

Though while this is more convenient for you, on the computer side, it is one more declared variable.

Comment: Would this actually change the original value if I went ObjectA = something? Or is this just manipulating a copy of the original?

Comment: Nope, you’re just copying the value into the new variable. As I mentioned, the trade off for easier code for you here is that you will have one more variable on your memory. Only you will know if that matters or not.

Comment: This applies only to the case where inside Object.ObjectTwo.Variable, Variable is a reference type. If it is a value type it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Hm... It's not exactly what I would've hoped for but because none else seems to have a better answer I will mark this as answer. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In C# 7, you can use [Ref Locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals).  Unlike most other approaches, this approach can be used safely even when operating on structs.

This approach is only available on fields.  Properties cannot be aliased using ref.

Below is an example.

```
struct bar
{
    public int myprop;
}

struct bash 
{
    public bar mybar;
}

void Main()
{
    bash bash1 = new bash();
    bash1.mybar.myprop = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(bash1.mybar.myprop); //Outputs 1 (Direct access)

    bar bar2 = bash1.mybar;
    bar2.myprop = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(bash1.mybar.myprop); //Outputs 1 (Bug: access via a copy)

    ref bar bar3 = ref bash1.mybar;
    bar3.myprop = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(bash1.mybar.myprop); //Outputs 3 (Ref Local)

    bar3 = new bar();
    bar3.myprop = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(bash1.mybar.myprop); //Outputs 4 (Ref local with assignment)
}
```

Comment: @Mawkey: I think C#7 requires Unity 2018.3 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

You can give yourself some syntactic sugar by implementing "shortcuts" that might get you closer to your goal.

```
public class ObjectOne
{
    public ObjectTwo ObjectTwo {get;set;}

    public VariableType Var {get{return ObjectTwo.Variable;}}
}
```

This allows you to write for example:

```
var one = new ObjectOne();

one.Var = something;
```

@Eric Lippert is right, this is only one possible solution the Question needs more information to be answered correctly.

Comment: Eric Lippert provides a generic implementation of such a short-cut class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982037/18192).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var shortCut = Object.ObjectTwo;    
shortCut.Variable  = something;
```

Comment: Of all the answers so far, this is the only correct one, and it is only correct if `ObjectTwo` is a reference type.

Comment: Indeed, it must be a reference type and not a value type. Up vote it if you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

The example `camera.backgroundColor.r = 1` from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711382/how-do-i-shorten-the-path-to-a-property#comment96213322_54711382) simply won't work. You will get the following error

> Cannot modify the return value of 'Camera.backgroundColor' because it is not a variable

and the reason has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp). The point is that in `Unity` the `Camera` itself is the `class` but the `Color` (the type of the `backgoundColor`) is mutable `struct`, be careful though they are evil.

---

> When you assign a new value to a variable of a value type, that value
>   is copied. When you assign a new value to a variable of a reference
>   type, the reference is copied, not the object itself

```
public class Camera
{
    public BackgroundColorValue backgroundColorValue { get; set; } 
        = new BackgroundColorValue();
    public BackgroundColorRef backgroundColorRef { get; set; } 
        = new BackgroundColorRef();
}

public struct BackgroundColorValue
{
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int g { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

public class BackgroundColorRef
{
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int g { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

var shortCutValue = cammera.backgroundColorValue;
var shortCutRef = cammera.backgroundColorRef;

shortCutValue.r = 5;
shortCutRef.r = 10;

//cammera.backgroundColorValue.r == 0, shortCutValue == 5
//cammera.backgroundColorRef.r == 10, shortCutValue == 10
```

The `value` types are copied by value so `shortCutValue` doesn't have any connection with the `camera.backgroundColor.r` except they have the same value in one period of their existance. On the other hand, `shortCutRef` is an actual shortcut and it will work until you change the reference to the `backgroundColorRef` which might be possible if `Camera` is mutable.

```
var shortCutRef = cammera.backgroundColorRef;
camera.backgroundColorRef = new BackgroundColorRef(); //link to shortcut broken
shortCutRef.r = 10;

//cammera.backgroundColorRef.r == 0, shortCutValue == 10
```

---

I am not sure if this is applicable in general, there might be some case Eric knows, but if you have `A.B.C.D....N.r` you could make a shortcut if `N` is actually `reference` type and to be sure the link with the shortcut will be unbreakable all types from N to A should be immutable. Otherwise, you could break a link somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local function (or on C# versions < 7.0 a delegate).

```
public void DoWork(SomeType thing, PropertyType value1, PropertyType value2)
{
    void Shortcut(PropertyType value) => thing.ThingTwo.Property = value;

    Shortcut(value1);
    Shortcut(value2);
}
```