# How to name the columns of a DGV with words from a list?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm new to C#.

I have 2 xml files.
And I want the results to be shown in a DataGridView. Because its a table.

Problem is, the DGV takes the **Name** and **Value** (from my class) as headliner for the DGV. But I want that the DGV takes the **xnames** from my function code as headliner.

My class:

```
public class ResultNames
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

my function code:

```
class FindFileContent
{
    public List<List<ResultNames>> GetInfos(string configFile, string dataFile)
    {
        //List<ResultNames> dataResult = new List<ResultNames>();
        List<List<ResultNames>> virtualTable = new List<List<ResultNames>>();

        XDocument config = XDocument.Load(configFile);

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = config.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
            .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("XPath"), y => (string)y.Attribute("Name"))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        XDocument data = XDocument.Load(dataFile);

        List<XElement> positions = data.Descendants("Position").ToList();

        foreach (XElement position in positions.Where(e => e.HasAttributes))
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attribute in position.Attributes().Where(a => dict.ContainsKey($"@{a.Name.LocalName}")))
            {
                string name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                string value = (string)attribute;
                string xName = dict["@" + name];

                //dataResult.Add(new ResultNames() { Name = xName, Value = value });
                virtualTable.Add(new List<ResultNames>());
                virtualTable.Last().Add(new ResultNames() { Name = xName, Value = value });

            }
        }
        return virtualTable;
  }
```

Here I want the **xName**, as headliner and the value as values under the right headline.

and here my outout:

```
FindFileContent fileContent = new FindFileContent();

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<List<ResultNames>> resultOfFiles = fileContent.GetInfos(configFile, file);

    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = resultOfFiles;         
}
```

As you see, I've tried it with a list in the list.. but that also didn't work.. can anybody help me?

Here a short xml from the first xml. From this I want that the DGV take
**Position, Gruppen-Nr, PositionsNr, ....** as heading for the columns.
Those things are in my list with the **xName**. Just want to get these in the DGV.

```
<ROOT>
 <Columns BaseXPath="//Orders/Position/">
  <Colum XPath="@PositionSK" Name="Position"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PosGroup" Name="Gruppen-Nr"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PosNumber" Name="PositionsNr"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PositionCommercialTypeSK" Name="Status"/>
  <Colum XPath="@BundlePositionSK" Name="BundlePositionSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="@MainPositionSK" Name="MainPositionSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="@SalesAgentPrice" Name="Preis"/>
  <Colum XPath="@BookingUnitSK" Name="Buch"/>
  <Colum XPath="@ContentComponentCommSK" Name="IKO"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PositionTypeSK" Name="PositionsTyp"/>
  <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = 
   PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementSK" 
   Name="AdvertisementSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = 
   PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementTypeSK" 
   Name="Formatvorgabe"/>
 </Columns>
</ROOT>
```

It should look like this:

Position | Gruppen-Nr | PositionsNr | Status | ... (all xName)

............. (all the Values)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673051/1506454 shows smth similar. instead of `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;` make it `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please share a *minimal* xml content and expected DataGridView columns.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want the output as heading for the columns. the Xname is e.g. "PosNumber, PosGroup, PositionTypeSK, ..." this should be my heading. und under that the values "3, 5, ...".
I will edit my question.

Comment: Instead of creating a `List<List<ResultNames>>`, create a `DataTable`. Then add columns to `DataTable` and use what you are extracting as `Name` property, as name of the `Column` of `DataTable`. Then add values as rows of the `DataTable`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei can you give me an example? never worked with DGV or DataTable before..

Comment: By the way, your column tags should be Colum → **n** ←

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create `DataTable` using the file which contains column definitions. Then load data to the `DataTable` from the file which contains data. Then set the `DataTable` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`:

```
//Create DataTable having desired columns
var columnsXml = XDocument.Load(@"d:\columns.xml");
var columns = columnsXml.Root.Element("Columns").Elements()
    .Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Attribute("Name").Value));
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(columns.ToArray());

//Then load data to DataTable
//here is some dummy data
dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

//Set DataSource of DataGridView
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Running above code in a form which contains a `DataGridView` you will see columns in DataGridView which expected header texts.