# How can I fill dataGrid rows with an array elements

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Wonder if somebody could help me.

How can I create a simplest `TwoWay` edited table that display an double array ?

[image: This how it look like in Winforms.]

For example `double arr[] = new double [] {90,60,45,30,10,1,0.8}`
Then I create `DataGrid` in XAML. How to bind every array element to appropriate gridRow. Or maybe easiest way to make it with any other WPF control that allows to calculate items for their indexes

Will be grateful to hear any of your answers.

Comment: it is easier to make with another data structure, e.g. DataTable. see [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673051/1506454), for example

Comment: you need an `ObservableCollection<DoubleType>` bound to `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` where DoubleType is a `DependecyObject` with two `DependecyProperties`

Comment: Think it could be applyed in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that "where DoubleType is a DependecyObject with two DependecyProperties" is plain nonsense. A binding source object does not need to be a DependencyObject. It should however implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: ASh. Your way is what I was looking for. Using DataTable same as winforms. Could you help once more? Now how to save values from the table in an array. How to get index of the table? Like dataTable.row(0).value   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explain my problem from other side.
I have an array

`double[] degree = { 90, 60, 45, 30, 10, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 10, 30, 45, 60, 90 };`

In winforms I fill table rows with it.

```
InitializeComponent();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(21);
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = degree [i]`
```

Like shown in the picture above. Now I am looking for simplest and useful way with WPF.

```
using System.Windows.Data;  // for table

public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Header name");  

        for (int i = 0; i < degree.Length; i++)
        dt.Rows.Add(degree[i]);

        DG.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;  // DG - name of DataGrid in which DataTable.
  }
```

This way table look like in the picture. But I can't get values from cells of "DataTable" use indexes (like "dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value") for further calculations or pass values of cells to another array. Someone offer to use collection of objects, but I don't find a way to create collection with array as property. Could someone offer a simple and applicable way to solve my problem.