# Dynamic columns on WPF

Tags: wpf

Assume we have a DataGrid like this :

[image]

First column is constant. others are come from database. In columns we display name of football players for example and below them we display some statistics about them .

What control do you suggest to use ?
If you suggest DataGrid how do I create columns and rows and connect them to data source ?

Any code example would be appreciated.

Comment: DataGrid has an "AutoGenerateColumns" property, which is true by default.  Isn't that what you need?

Comment: This is a transposed `Datagrid`. The problem is much easier without it. You should verify it as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is typically called a pivot table or Matrix.  See [Dynamic data matrix WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138441/dynamic-data-matrix-wpf) for an example of how to do so in WPF.

---

**Edit:** If you are not trying to pivot, but just rotate it 90 degrees, there is a rather good answer on how to do that, too: [WPF horizontal DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid).  Basically just use a couple of LayoutTransforms to rotate the whole thing, then another set to rotate the cells back to normal.

Comment: It doesn't sound like he's pivoting on data. Simply transposing the column headers.

Comment: @Jim, You may be right.  I took the "And then we show statistics about them" to mean multiple rows.

Comment: Yes there are multiple rows.