# How do I display my List into a C# Datagrid?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datagrid

I have a classroom full of students and I've tracked which activity they've done and what score they achieved on each activity using this code:

```
public class TrackActivity
{
     public String StudentName {get; set;}
     public String ActivityName {get; set;}
     public int ActivityScore {get; set;}  // out of 10 points
}
```

I currently have a List of "TrackActivity" called lstTrackScores, such that:

```
Barbara, juggling, 9
Barbara, cycling, 7
Chris, cycling, 9
Dennis, juggling, 8
Dennis, cycling, 6
Dennis, archery, 10
```

I don't know in advance how many unique students are in my List, but I do find out at run-time the maximum number of activities each student can participate in. How do I display the above information in a datagrid such that the number of unique students act as the number of rows (here, 3: Barbara, Chris, and Dennis), and the number of activities (here, 3: juggling, cycling, archery) act as the number of columns?

Then, in each cell, there would be a score if the student participated in that activity, and a blank if they did not participate in that activity. Ultimately, I'd like to display the above in a datagrid without having to change my class.

I tried to determine the number of unique students by doing this:

```
lstTrackScores.Select(x => x.StudentNames).Distinct().Count();
```

I think I want to create a 2-dimensional array with number of rows equal to the Count above, and number of columns equal to 3. Then, somehow, I display that array to a Datagrid, but I don't know how to do this. I'm using C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically want is a [DataMatrix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36462/Binding-a-ListView-to-a-Data-Matrix) where rows and columns are dynamically dependend on the data input.

[image]

Theres also an appropriate answer on Stackoverflow which will help
[Dynamic data matrix WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138441/dynamic-data-matrix-wpf)

You will have to build a 2d array and feed it into the Grid.

Comment: That snapshot is exactly what I"m trying to do, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

convert the result of the query to a generic List and pass it as a datasource to datagrid.

Comment: He also needs dynamic columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
           yourdatagrid.DataSource = yourlist;
```