# Display 2d array in DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to get a DataGrid to display the contents of an `object[][]`. This'll be read-only so I don't care about notification changes or anything like that. Setting `ItemSource` to an `object[][]` simply displays the properties of `Array` in the grid, and using `List<List<object>>` instead does the same, which is decidedly unhelpful.

The number of columns in each 1d array can be arbitary; I simply want an unnamed column to be created for each array element in each row. How can I do this?

Comment: 5 points from 10K, congrats :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array/4002409#4002409). This will also enable editing of the values. Since you're just interested in displaying them it might be easier to use the answer from *Jobi Joy* if using the DataGrid isn't a requirement.

To make a short version of the answer from that question. You'll need a Ref class

```
public class Ref<T>
{  
    private readonly Func<T> getter;   
    private readonly Action<T> setter;  
    public Ref(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)   
    {   
        this.getter = getter;   
        this.setter = setter;   
    }  
    public T Value { get { return getter(); } set { setter(value); } }   
}
```

And a helper class to get dynamic columns from the 2d array

```
public class BindingHelper
{
    public DataView GetBindable2DViewFromIList<T>(IList list2d)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < ((IList)list2d[0]).Count; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Ref<T>));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list2d.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        for (int i = 0; i < list2d.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ((IList)list2d[i]).Count; j++)
            {
                int a = i;
                int b = j;
                Ref<T> refT = new Ref<T>(() => (list2d[a] as IList<T>)[b], z => { (list2d[a] as IList<T>)[b] = z; });                    
                dataView[i][j] = refT;
            }
        }
        return dataView;
    }
}
```

After that you can use ItemsSource like this

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" 
          RowHeaderWidth="0" 
          ColumnHeaderHeight="0" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/> 

dataGrid.ItemsSource = BindingHelper.GetBindable2DViewFromIList<object>(m_2DArray);

private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) 
{ 
    DataGridTextColumn column = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn; 
    Binding binding = column.Binding as Binding; 
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath(binding.Path.Path + ".Value");
}
```

Comment: I ended up just creating rows in the DataTable using `Rows.Add(rowArray)`, and getting a DataView using `AsDataView` extension method.