# Grid Table in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to create a grid. It should be editable

And i should set row and column count.

for example

```
mygrid.RowCount = 3;
mygrid.ColumnCount = 3;
```

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

How to BIND 2D array to DataGrid?

Comment: How to create such grid?

Comment: Sergey, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array , especially the answer of Meleak (not the accepted answer). I think what he offers does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the WPF DataGrid control.  It displays a grid of cells that correspond to a collection of objects (rows) containing properties (columns).  You need to supply the data storage - a collection of objects. The number of objects in the collection (the collection count) will determine the number of rows in the grid.  The DataGrid supports editing the data in the UI.

This example defines three columns and binds them to the A, B, and C properties of the data object.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Height="200" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Name="dataGrid1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="200">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=A}" MinWidth="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=B}" MinWidth="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=C}" MinWidth="50" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You will need to assign (in code or using data binding) a collection of objects with these properties to the DataGrid's ItemsSource property, as with any other ItemsControl.  Something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
        public class DataObject
        {
            public int A { get; set; }
            public int B { get; set; }
            public int C { get; set; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var list = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();
            list.Add(new DataObject() { A = 6, B = 7, C = 5 });
            list.Add(new DataObject() { A = 5, B = 8, C = 4 });
            list.Add(new DataObject() { A = 4, B = 3, C = 0 });
            this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

And the result looks like this, when editing the center cell:

[image: WPF DataGrid]

Side note: the WPF Grid class is only for layout.  It does not provide data editing support.

Comment: I need a dynamic number of rows and columns. I cant have a 100..000 properties. I have to bind a 2D array to DataGrid

Comment: So use a 2D collection:  A List<List<int>>, and bind each column to an element of the array:  List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>(3);  list.Add(new List<int>(new int[] { 6, 7, 5 }));
(etc) this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;  in the xaml, set the columns up like this: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[0]}" MinWidth="50" /> then Path=[1] etc.  You will still have to write code to add column definitions when you resize your data, but that's not hard.

Comment: On the other hand, if what you really want is an arbitrary 2D cell matrix and you don't want to do the work of managing the data storage and UI upkeep, perhaps you should be using Excel instead?  ;>

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general technique for creating an `ItemsControl` that uses a `Grid` to lay out its items.  In this example (which uses an XML data source), the `ItemsSource` is a collection of items with `Row`, `Column`, and `Data` properties.

Note the use of `ItemContainerStyle`.  This is necessary here because in order for the `Grid` control to use the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties, those properties must be attached to the objects inserted into the grid - if you try to set them on the `TextBox` that the `ItemsTemplate` is generating, the grid won't see them, because it's looking at the generated `ContentPresenter`, not the `TextBox` inside it.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data">
      <x:XData>
        <Data xmlns="">
          <Item Row="0" Column="0" Data="0,0"/>
          <Item Row="1" Column="1" Data="1,1"/>
          <Item Row="2" Column="1" Data="2,1"/>
          <Item Row="3" Column="2" Data="3,2"/>
          <Item Row="4" Column="4" Data="4,4"/>
          <Item Row="4" Column="3" Data="4,3"/>
        </Data>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Page.Resources>
  <DockPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Data/Item}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Grid>  
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>    
              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>    
              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>    
              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>    
              <RowDefinition Height="30"/>    
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          </Grid>        
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
          <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding XPath=@Row}"/>
          <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding XPath=@Column}"/>
        </Style>
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=@Data, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I need a dynamic number of rows and columns.

Comment: It is kind of annoying that the built-in `Grid` can't do this.  But it's not hard to subclass it to add this functionality - see http://blog.rag.no/post/A-simpler-(and-dynamic)-Grid-control-for-WPF.aspx.