# Two way binding between DataGrid and an array

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, datagrid

I have an an array called:

```
string[,] TableData;
```

Can I link its content with a DataGrid control using binding?

If possible, I would like the user to be able to edit the Grid and reflect the changes in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question: [How to populate a WPF grid based on a 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array)

You can use [this control](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?1bw6dm9y11fbmnu) called `DataGrid2D` ([source code here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?tm1arm230rr1tgi)). To use it just add a reference to DataGrid2DLibrary.dll, add this namespace

```
xmlns:dg2d="clr-namespace:DataGrid2DLibrary;assembly=DataGrid2DLibrary"
```

and then create a DataGrid2D and bind it to your IList, 2D array or 1D array like this

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2D Name="dataGrid2D"
                 ItemsSource2D="{Binding Int2DList}"/>
```

The users will be able to edit the data and changes made in the `DataGrid` will be reflected in the 2D Array

Comment: @Thanks Meleak, I've been reading that but I was interested in filling a **DataGrid** with a 2D Array, not a Grid of components.

Comment: @Jaime Oro: Updated my answer. I had the same requirement in a previous project and created a subclassed `DataGrid` which you can try

Answer (score 2):

**You can't bind a matrix to a `DataGrid`**. However, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could transform it to an array of `class`.

What is the content of your matrix? Why don't you try something like this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string a, string b)
    {
        Debug.Assert(a != null);
        Debug.Assert(b != null);

        this.A = a;
        this.B = b;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate something as follows:

```
MyClass[] source = { new MyClass("A", "B"), new MyClass("C", "D") };
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = source;
```

Alternatively, if you can't modify the type of your source, try to use LINQ to project it:

```
var source = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0))
              select new MyClass(matrix[i, 0], matrix[i, 1])).ToList();
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
```

Comment: The problem here is that my Matrix can have any number of Cols/Rows.

Comment: This worked well for me - I had a fixed number of columns. I used indexers so I could access it as an array or as a data bound List<rows>.

Comment: This only works of you have a static number of columns and rows

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be to use the build in WPF Datagrid and project your Array to a View class which will be bound.

Do you want your users to be able to add rows? If yes binding to an array is not possible because you can't add rows.

If you have any number of columns you should be able to project your array to a dynamic object and set the AutoGenerateColumns property of the datagrid to true. Do your columns have names?

Comment: I want the users to be able to add rows and cols. Cols have no names.