# DataGrid2D set TextAlignment in DataGridCell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using the DataGrid2D posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362124/two-way-binding-between-datagrid-and-an-array). I can't seem to figure out a way to align the Text inside the Cells (i.e. right, center, left). For the default WPF4 DataGrid I just set

```
<Style x:Key="GridTextColumnStyleLeftAligned" TargetType="TextBlock">
   <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
   <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Here TextAlignment does the trick. But when using the ItemsSource2D Property to bind it to a 2-dimensional Array this does not work anymore.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I am using the Alternative Style which the DataGrid2D Provides. There we already have this definiton:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
...
```

If I change it here it works. I will have to rewrite the class a bit, for me to set the Alignment in XAML instead of with a style.