# Databinding error 40 dataGrid2d

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Due to [Two way binding between DataGrid and an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362124/two-way-binding-between-datagrid-and-an-array) I want to make such a `grid`, but there is still an error and I don't know how to eliminate it.

Here is all the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string[,] _data2D;
    public string[,] Data2D
    {
        get { return _data2D; }
        set { _data2D = value; }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _data2D = new string[9 , 9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                _data2D[i, j] = "0";
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid2D.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:dg2d="clr-namespace:DataGrid2DLibrary;assembly=DataGrid2DLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <dg2d:DataGrid2D Background="Azure" UseModifiedDataGridStyle="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ColumnWidth="30" DataContext="this"
                         RowHeight="30" HeadersVisibility="None" Name="dataGrid2D" ItemsSource2D="{Binding Data2D}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 

BindingExpression path error: 

'Data2D' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1178749465)'. 

BindingExpression:Path=Data2D; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1178749465);

target element is 'DataGrid2D' (Name='dataGrid2D'); 

target property is 'ItemsSource2D' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Anyone knows how to help me? It makes sometimes not all controls rendering :/ Sometimes some control render in half etc.

Comment: Grid does not show up

Comment: Yes, it's works but it has error anyway and if there is many controls, sometimes all renders sometimes not. It's because of this binding, when I disabled it, all controls always renders

Comment: Where can I see this error?

Comment: debug output window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `DataContext` in two places:

In `MainWindow()`:

```
dataGrid2D.DataContext = this;
```

And in `XAML` you have:

```
DataContext="this"
```

Delete `DataContext` property from your `XAML`:

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2D Background="Azure" UseModifiedDataGridStyle="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ColumnWidth="30" 
                         RowHeight="30" HeadersVisibility="None" Name="dataGrid2D" ItemsSource2D="{Binding Data2D}"/>
```