# Programmatically Binding DataGrid to List array

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have to List of Data :

```
List<string[]> dataRow = new List<string[]>();
```

1. every string[] array are full with 30 data for each row.
2. Column Name are already exists.

I'm trying to display it like this :

XAML :

```
<DataGrid Margin="8,259,8,8" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2" Name="MyDataGrid" />
```

C# :

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataRow;

foreach( string[] cellContent in dataRow )
{
  foreach( string text in cellContent )
  {
    var column = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
      Binding = new Binding(text)
    };
    MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
   }
 }
```

but i got a "ContextSwitchDeadlock" Error. How can i solve this?

Thank u  for Helping

**EDIT : solved but not with the databinding Way**

I solved it like this :

```
List<string> ColumnName = new List<string>();
List<string[]> dataRow = new List<string[]>();
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

 // Fill Array ColumnName and dataRow Here

foreach (string text in ColumnName)
{
   myTable.Columns.Add(text);
}
foreach (string[] cellContent in dataRow)
{
   myTable.Rows.Add(cellContent);
}
DatensatzGrid.ItemsSource = myTable.AsDataView();
```

Thank u for all the reply!!

Comment: what do you try to achieve with that line `MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyDataGrid`

Comment: That is not databinding in your solution.

Comment: Okay! im not a profi but this work! can u explain ur mind? and with my solution can we translate it to databinding? Thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataGrid` control doesn't support Binding to 2D arrays, `List<List..>>` etc.

See this question: [How to populate a WPF grid based on a 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array)

I created a subclassed `DataGrid` ([DataGrid2D](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?1bw6dm9y11fbmnu)) to achieve this a while back.

To use it just add a reference to DataGrid2DLibrary.dll, add this namespace

```
xmlns:dg2d="clr-namespace:DataGrid2DLibrary;assembly=DataGrid2DLibrary"
```

and then create a DataGrid2D and bind it to your IList, 2D array or 1D array like this

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2D Name="MyDataGrid"
                 ItemsSource2D="{Binding DataRow}"/>
```

Since dataRow is a field a not a property binding won't work, but just setting the `ItemsSource2D` in code behind will be enough to display it

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource2D = dataRow;
```

- [`DataGrid2D` Library](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?1bw6dm9y11fbmnu)
- [`DataGrid2D` Source](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?tm1arm230rr1tgi)