# bind datagrid to List<string[]> wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

I have a custom data structure that is pretty much a list of string arrays that I want to display in a (virtual) datagrid in WPF. All the examples of binding I have seen have been to objects with known properties such as a Colors object with a Blue and Red property.

My data is being populated from a SQL query and returns an unknown number of columns.

How can I bind to this type of structure?

(I don't want to use something like ObservableCollection for performance reasons: my data is going to be static so I don't need INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: Are you using WPF3 or WPF4? Basically which type of Grid?

Comment: I'm using WPF4 - it's the DataGrid that was formerly part of the WPF Toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following question: [How to populate a WPF grid based on a 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array)

If you're only interested in displaying your 2d data then the answer from *Jobi Joy* will get it done using a `Grid`.

If you also want to be able to edit the data then you can use a control I created a while back for this purpose called `DataGrid2D` which subclasses `DataGrid`

To use it, just add a reference to DataGrid2DLibrary.dll, add this namespace

```
xmlns:dg2d="clr-namespace:DataGrid2DLibrary;assembly=DataGrid2DLibrary"
```

and then bind it to your `List<string[]>` like this

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2D ItemsSource2D="{Binding ListStringArrayProperty}"/>
```

- [DataGrid2D Library](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?1bw6dm9y11fbmnu)
- [DataGrid2D Source](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?tm1arm230rr1tgi)

Comment: The download URL is broken.  Google currently returns this URL instead: http://www.mediafire.com/?9xrq5obde90b67o

Comment: @Erij J: I just tried it and it seems to be working fine now. Are you still having trouble with the link? Maybe a temporary problem with mediafire. I'll move it to dropbox instead when I get the chance