# How to create a matrix of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, matrix

I need to create a static matrix (need to be datagrid)  10*10 that contain buttons in each cell.
Any one have an idea how to do that?

Thank you all.

Xmal:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Arr}">  
        <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>  
            <DataTemplate>  
                <Button />  
            </DataTemplate>  
        </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>  
    </DataGrid>  
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication4  
{
    /// <summary>  
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml  
    /// </summary>  
    public partial class MainWindow : Window  
    {  
       private List<string> m_Arr;  

        public MainWindow()  
        {  
             InitializeComponent();  
             DataContext = this;  

            m_Arr = new List<string>();  
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
            {  
                m_Arr.Add(i.ToString());  
            }  
         }  

        public List<string> Arr  
        {
            get { return m_Arr; }  
            set { m_Arr = value; }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have tried to create an 2d array of buttons in code behind, and bind it to the a data grid, but it didnt give me the expected result,

Comment: I have tried to create a List<List<int>> and bind it to a datagrid and this gave me a matrix of int's but i didnt succeeded to change it to buttons instead of int...

Comment: And just what part of the result was not expected?   Don't use the matrix tag - it is for mathematical matrix and in matrix algebra.

Comment: instead of buttons i get the toString (system.window.controls.buttons)

Comment: You probably want something like an `ItemsControl` instead of a `DataGrid`, and to define the `ItemTemplate` as a `Button`. I have some [examples on my blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) that should help explain the process. A very simple way of doing it would be to change the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `UniformGrid` that is 10x10, and put all your items in a single `List<T>`, or you can use `List<List<T>>` and use two nested ItemsControls, one with a Vertical StackPanel for the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and the other with a Horizontal StackPanel

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to bind an array of buttons to a datagrid.

Instead, you should build an array of commands, bind the itemssource of your itemscontrol to your list of commands, and datatemplate those commands as buttons bound back to the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can as you stated on your comment, create a 2D array. However, the default WPF `DataGrid` does not support a 2D `ItemsSource`

You can for example use the `DataGrid2D` control introduced here:

[How to populate a WPF grid based on a 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array)

I personally work with that and... It works fine!

Bottom note: Don't create array of `Buttons` to use as an ItemsSource. You should rather do the following, for example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
  <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding}" />
     </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

where `MyList` is an `IList<string>`

Do it as a test. Then you can use a more complex `ItemsSource`, including the content string + the `Command` to call when clicking on the button. Way cleaner, and MVVM-compliant =)

Comment: Oops, I did a small mistake, give me a minute to edit this ^^

Comment: Fixed, an `ItemTemplate` must contain a `DataTemplate` first... This is what happens when I write code without Visual Studio's help =)

Comment: Your code is wrong. Look at your `Button`: you didn't put anything as a Content!

Comment: Oh, you are binding a List<string> (one dimension only). In this case, you should use a `ListBox` rather than a `DataGrid`

Comment: As stated in the answer, go for the exact same idea, but instead of using a `DataGrid`, use the `DataGrid2D` you'll find in the embedded link => bind it to a 2D array and let the magic happen =)

Comment: Ok... its really works, i have 2d array but the datagrid display string and not buttons, ny idea why?

Comment: You probably forgot the template! Default display is string, to have buttons you have to fill the field `ItemTemplate` as I showed you above