# Show progress and/or detect completion of DataGrid rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

There appears to be a delay after assigning a large data-set to a DataGrid.  This delay occurs after the assignment to ItemsSource or DataSource completes, and is non-blocking.  In particular, after assigning a large array of data (approx. 200,000 elements) as the source for a DataGrid, there is a 3-4 second delay before the items appear on screen.  I am certain this occurs after the assignment and is non-blocking because all code following the assignment executes immediately.

Are there any settings within DataGrid that might help decrease the delay I'm experiencing, and, more importantly, is there any way to know when the process has finished and the items are visible on screen so I can inform the user of the process and when it has completed?

What I've tried for optimization:

- Swapping ItemsSource and DataSource to access data - No noticeable improvement
- Enable Column/Row virtualization - No noticeable improvement
- Disabled column auto-sizing - Minor improvement

Additionally, the DataGrid is contained only in a grid used for positioning, no ScrollViewer or anything of that nature, and I am using something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid) to bind the data to the DataGrid.

What I've tried for notification:

- Subscribed to LayoutUpdated event of the DataGrid - triggers too often, not sure how to tell which call is the one I want.

I'm open to suggestions for further optimization, but really need to find a way to know when the information is visible on screen.  A delay is acceptable, and likely as the size of the data-set increases, but I need a way to keep the user informed.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_NPS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                  ColumnWidth="*" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The C# can be found at the link under "What I've tried for optimization"

Comment: Background worker sounds good for this.

Comment: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&checkda=1&ct=1409324556&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fmsdn.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2flibrary%2fsystem.componentmodel.backgroundworker%2528v%3dvs.110%2529.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US

Comment: @sparkysword No, actually IProgress<T> is preferred now. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TimothyS. I'm not around here as much as I used to be, because I'm very busy these days. You're probably breaking UI virtualization by doing stupid things like putting your `DataGrid` in a `ScrollViewer` or something like that. Also, a `DataSet` (if that's what you're using) is a really crappy data structure, you should code properly instead of using that.

Comment: @HighCore - To HighCore from a moderator: Stop being rude and abusive to people asking questions here. We don't "ban" anyone for asking questions. Even if you feel someone is not putting in the effort in asking a question, you can point this out in a polite and constructive manner, or simply downvote, vote to close and move on. There's no need to be aggressive towards askers, and I'm getting tired of cleaning up your comments.

Comment: Reformatted the question to be clearer and to include what I've tried so far.  Not going to include the code because the question is about what events/etc are available within .NET, not about how to use any of them or about my code.

Comment: @TimothyS. to make it clear: loading a DataGrid in WPF should be immediate regardless of the amount of rows (even if it's 400 million), due to WPF's built-in UI virtualization. The problem you're describing here is either related to a bad layout breaking UI virtualization, or your data structure not being adequate for WPF's DataBinding. Either case, I insist you post relevant code and XAML, because your question is very unclear. There is no such thing as `DataSource` in WPF, so I really have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @TimothyS. I recommend you get rid of that (rather dubious) third party code and use a proper `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is the standard, well-known, accepted, recommended data structure to bind to WPF ItemsControls. Using reflection on your data items is not going to help performance at all. And I'm not really sure why such thing would even be needed to begin with.

Comment: The data being bound is in a 2D array - I asked earlier how to go about binding it and was told it wasn't possible, and redirected to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645095/how-do-i-bind-a-jagged-array-of-strings-to-a-datagrid-in-c), and pulled the code from there.  I'll look into replacing it with an ObservableCollection, but in the mean time I'd much appreciate answers pertaining to the issue of detecting completion.

Comment: @TimothyS. `The data being bound is in a 2D array` - Create a proper ViewModel which turns your data into a proper Data Structure usable by WPF (without using Reflection). `detecting completion` is not possible unless you use asynchronous tasks to slowly add items to the list. The problem is not the UI, but the amount of reflection being used by your data structure. Reflection is the slowest possible solution in .Net. Always avoid it unless you really need it. In this case, it is just a matter of properly modeling your data.

Comment: BTW, if this is all about loading data from excel, I recommend you use [LINQ To Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) instead. This tool provides a way to create a strongly typed object model based on an Excel Sheet, which is then suitable for WPF DataBinding and does not resort to reflection or other bad performing techniques. If you need it to be generic for an unknown Excel sheet structure, you can even create these strongly typed object models on the fly and load them with MEF or the like. In any case, reflection is not going to allow you to achieve good performance with big data.

Comment: What makes a data structure "proper" and usable by WPF?  Would just an ObservableCollection of a class with public properties work or are there additional requirements?

Comment: @TimothyS. yes. In fact, WPF is able to bind to any `IEnumerable<T>`. Again, the problem is not the UI framework, but the technique you're using to load the data. Reflection is very very slow.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I'll look into the LINQ to Excel as well, but if you want to write a short paragraph summarizing that solution (create a class to store the individual "objects", use an ObservableCollection<T> to hold them, bind like so, etc) I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I never did find an event to hook into so I would be notified when it was done rendering, I did manage a great deal of optimization from the various comments and answers.  This was done largely by ditching an implementation that used reflection for something faster.

First, in place of using a custom class for the source of my DataGrid, it was provided with a simple array of a custom class with several public properties.  Those properties were set from data read by the Excel interop (the LINQ to Excel alternative that was proposed turned out to be slower than my own solution).  This was bound to the datagrid and load times were reduced to a couple seconds for 100k rows, with around 200k-500k cells total.

That delay is still found after the array of items is built and bound to the DataGrid, but the delay is far more acceptable than it was before.

Finally, since I needed to be able to read from files without knowing which columns I wanted until the user specified at run-time I built a system to generate classes to fill dynamically.  I did this by building a string containing the code for such a class then using C#'s run-time compilation features to obtain efficiency close to that of a hard-coded class.

Finally, in order to avoid having to use reflection to assign values to the properties in these custom objects I built a simple interface specifying a method that takes the row of generic data from the spreadsheet and initializes the properties internally.

Here is the interface:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    // Used by classes built by an ExcelQueryableFactory to permit 
    // initialization without knowledge of the underlying properties.
    public interface IExcelQueryable  {
        void BuildFrom(object[] data);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of the code generated for one of the custom classes:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class CustomClass0 : IExcelQueryable {
        public double myNumber { get; set; }
        public string myString { get; set; }
        public void BuildFrom(object[] data) {
            myNumber = (double)data[0];
            myString = (string)data[1];
        }
    }
}
```

It's definitely not the best code I've ever written, but I figured I'd share it anyways on the off chance someone else showed up with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [BusyIndicator](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) control included in [Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) :

You just have to set `IsBusy` property and it will look like below, use an async `Task` like I'll show below, enable it, do your thing, disable it.

[image]

---

You should use `IProgress<T>` instead as it's the 'official' way to run background tasks, as you can see below it is less cumbersome than `BackgroundWorker`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // simulate some long work
            IProgress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(handler);
            Action action = () =>
            {
                int length = 10;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    double d = 1.0d/length*(i + 1);
                    progress.Report(d);
                }
            };

            await Task.Run(action);
        }

        private void handler(double value)
        {
            ProgressBar.Value = value*100;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Last thing,

It's better to use [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) than assigning manually `ItemsSource`.

On your XAML just define your data grid as follows:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Then on your code use it like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyObject MyObject { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyObject = new MyObject();

        this.DataContext = MyObject;
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MyObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

As much as possible try to avoid directly manipulating the data grid, it will only make your life easier.

---

**To get to the point of your question**

I don't know about a mechanism telling you where is the `DataGrid` process at, but by using a control like above which appears over it, this is certainly a good user experience, he is notified that he has to wait, period.

Additionally you can provide a cancel button but I'm not sure if that would fit well/apply in your case.

Comment: I'll look into shifting to IProgress, but the issue is that I have no way of telling when it's finished.  I can assign the DataContext or ItemsSource, and that finishes almost instantly, the code continues, but the GUI doesn't update for some time (about 3-4 seconds for 200k cells).  I already have a progress bar, and could shift it to a modal without too much trouble, but I have no way to know when to turn off the animation.

Comment: I don't see a mechanism clearly providing this, maybe you can try to hook to some events like [SourceUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) or [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated(v=vs.110).aspx), if they get called at the right time then you will be able to do what you want. Other than that such feature can probably be found on a commercial product ...

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention but 200K rows is a lot, keep in mind that M$ DataGrid is quite slow. See these hints http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765128/361899 and make sure to disable column auto-width.

Comment: I've looked into those suggestions with some success in optimizing the process.  I also updated the question to better reflect my problem, and what I've tried thus far.