# dispay data matrix with different number of columns in each row

Tags: wpf

I need to display ,in a WPF app, a 'data matrix' that has no fixed tabular structure i.e.

data row 1: aaa bb ccc 
data row 2: 222 $$ ddddd eeee 
... 
all data is in a list of arrays.

i need to show this data and enable a user to scroll through it. 
the strange data structure comes from a textual flat file, and i cannot change this.

i have read a lot, and experimented with a list-view and a grid-view, but so far i am only able to get:

**1.** dymanic column creation, but this is no good since i have a different schema for each row

**2.** rendering each row of data as (delimited/formatted) text. but this is no good since all row data is endign up in a single cell (obviously).

**3.** (*havn't done this yet, hoping to avoid*) have lots of data templates with triggers, each with a diffrent column count - say from 5 to 40 - to acomodate vast majority of row types.

**my question is:** how do i bind this data to a list-like / grid-like scrollable view ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One pass to find the maximum number of columns.  Build a simple Row class that has a property cols string[maxColCount].  Build the maxColCount columns for a GridView in code bind and bind the source to cols[x].

Comment: @Blam hmmm , im going to try this. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the ability to select an item, you can use nested [ItemsControls](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/)

Simply bind the first `ItemsControl` to your collection of arrays, and set the `ItemTemplate` to another `ItemsControl` which binds to the array of values.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="300" Width="400">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfArrays}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"  Width="50" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Can this method be adapted to produce a table (e.g. DataGrid or GridView) rather than a series of stackpanels?

Comment: @StephenHolt I don't think so, or at least not easily. You could set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `Grid`, however you'd need to know how many Rows and Columns your `Grid` needs, and what `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` each item goes in. What features do a `DataGrid` or `GridView` have that this wouldn't? (Note that this will result in tabular data because the width of each "Cell" is hardcoded to 50 - You could probably make that dynamic using a `Grid` and `Grid.SharedSizeScope`, but it's better on performance to hardcode a width if you can)

Comment: @Rachel thanks (+1) for the fast response, i would like to have edit capability also (even though for now i`ll settle for read only)

Comment: @Menahem You could use `TextBoxes` instead of `TextBlocks` for editing, although your binding will have to change to `Text="{Binding Path=.}` since you can't use a two-way binding without specifying a Path. Or to duplicate a DataGrid's functionality, use a `ContentControl` with it's `ContentTemplate` set to a `TextBlock`, and change the `ContentTemplate` to a `TextBox` OnClick :)

Comment: @Rachel struggling to grasp all this, i`m trying this now. thanks again :)

Comment: @Rachel I guess I was thinking of the ability to resize columns, have lines between the cells, that sort of thing. I guess you could build all that into the templates for the stackpanels but seems a lot of work for something you usually get for free!

Comment: @StephenHolt I just remembered that I saw a SO answer before where someone created a DataGrid2D control that is meant to be bound to a 2D array. You can find the source code an explanation for it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4002409/302677) - Might be worth checking out :)

Comment: @Rachel i have seen the 2D grid, but your solution of nested `ItemControl`s is a better fit for me. i have tried it (nested) with virtualizing stack panels and a 10Mb `List<Array>`, but it just sucks up a 100`s MB of memory and CPU and never gets to the point of showing any GUI. any ideas?

Comment: @Menahem No sorry, I've never used the 2D grid control myself

Comment: @Rachel OK, ended up using a `ItemssControl` nested in a `Listview` and this list`s `VirtualizingStackPanel` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One pass to find the maximum number of columns.
Build a simple Row class that has a property cols string[maxColCount].
Build the maxColCount columns for a GridView in code bind and bind the source to cols[x].

The compiler needs a property but you can bind the column to an collection name index
Syntax for building and binding a GridViewColumn

```
            gvc = new GridViewColumn();
            gvch = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            gvch.Content = fd.FieldDef.DispName;
            gvch.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            if (fd.FieldDef.Sort)
            {
                gvch.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(SortClick);
                gvch.Tag = fd.FieldDef.Name;
            }

            // if (fd.ID == 0 || fd.ID == 1) gvc.Width = 60; sID, sParID
            if (!fd.AppliedDispGrid) gvc.Width = 0;
            gvc.Header = gvch;

            gvBinding = new Binding();
            gvBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            gvBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DocFields[" + sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex.ToString() + "].DispValueShort");

            template = new DataTemplate();
            textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, gvBinding);
            textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextTrimmingProperty, TextTrimming.WordEllipsis);

            // <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis" />

            template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
            template.VisualTree.AppendChild(textblock);

            gvc.CellTemplate = template;

            gvSearchResults.Columns.Add(gvc);
```

Comment: i accepted Rachel`s answer because i ended up using it, but that doesn't mean your solution would not work. someone else might find it helpful too.