# How to bind an 2D array bool[][] to a WPF DataGrid (one-way)?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a matrix kind datagrid like this.

[image]

this grid is designed entirely in XAML

Now how to insert values into these datagridcell with 2 dimensional array ?
the values which is needed to be inserted must be of `bool` datatype (either TRUE or FALSE).
Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my approach for a MVVM scenario, using a converter which creates a DataView which can be bound to the grids `ItemsSource`. It's for a special Matrix datatype which holds doubles, but you'll be able to modify it yourself for your requirements:

```
public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var array = value as Matrix;
        if (array == null) return null;

        //var array = ILMath.rand(3, 5);

        var rows = array.Dimensions[0];
        var columns = array.Dimensions[1];

        var t = new DataTable();
        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString()));
        }

        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            var newRow = t.NewRow();
            for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                var v = array[r, c];

                // Round if parameter is set
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    int digits;
                    if (int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out digits))
                        v = Math.Round(v, digits);
                }

                newRow[c] = v;
            }

            t.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }


        return t.DefaultView;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Define a resource for the converter:

```
<converter:MatrixToDataViewConverter x:Key="MatrixToDataViewConverter" />
```

And use it like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix, Converter={StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
```

It doesn't allow two way binding, though...

**EDIT**

Here's the version for an array bool[][]:

```
public class BoolArrayToDataViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var array = value as bool[,];
        if (array == null) return null;

        var rows = array.GetLength(0);
        if (rows == 0) return null;

        var columns = array.GetLength(1);
        if (columns == 0) return null;

        var t = new DataTable();

        // Add columns with name "0", "1", "2", ...
        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString()));
        }

        // Add data to DataTable
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            var newRow = t.NewRow();
            for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                newRow[c] = array[r, c];
            }
            t.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return t.DefaultView;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix, Converter={StaticResource BoolArrayToDataViewConverter}}"/>
```

And this is what it looks like in the very raw version. You can then style the DataGrid and edit it's templates, but this is another question...

[image: UI]

Comment: I do not want two way binding though. thank u so much. i wil try and get back to u

Comment: @user1221765 You need to modify the example a little bit, because it's written for a custom Matrix type. It's pretty easy though, you need to replace matrix with the datatype youre using (bool[][]?) and change assignment of rows and columns, rows = array.length, columns=array[0].length (check for null before), for example. Spare the rounding bits altogether, as you won't round your bools, do you? Do you manage to do it, or do you need advice?

Comment: If you can modify it, it would be helpful @Marc.. i will also try in parallel. thanks

Comment: @user1221765: Have a look at my edited answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: danke Marc. I guess I have to add MinimalValueConverter in the ItemsSource like this - ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix, Converter={StaticResource MinimalValueConverter }}"

Comment: sorry for troubling you. can you please paste how will the output looks like from your PC ?

Comment: @user1221765 See my answer. I've modified the converter code as well, it makes more sense to use bool[,] instead of bool[][], but it depends on your data.

Comment: sorry, I get an empty datagrid @Marc :( I used the same converter as yours and bind it to my datagrid