# Changing background color of cells in DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, converters, wpfdatagrid, dataview

I used the following links to display my 2 dimensional data in a table:

[How to bind an 2D array bool[][] to a WPF DataGrid (one-way)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812020/how-to-bind-an-2d-array-bool-to-a-wpf-datagrid-one-way?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)

**All is working except that the background color is not changing (and the converter method is not even being hit).  Can someone tell me what's going on?**

Below I post a complete, minimal example.  I'm not wedded to any of these ideas (using a DataView to bind my IEnumerable> for example) so feel free to suggest alternative methods.  My only hard requirement is that in my real project, the data is given as IEnumerable>

Here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

        List<Column> row1 = new List<Column>()
        {
            new Column(){Make = Make.Ford,OperatingStatus =  OperatingStatus.Broken},
            new Column(){Make = Make.Honda, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Unknown}
        };
        List<Column> row2 = new List<Column>()
        {
            new Column() {Make = Make.GM, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Working},
            new Column() {Make = Make.Toyota, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Broken}
        };

        List<List<Column>> data = new List<List<Column>>();
        data.Add(row1);
        data.Add(row2);
        vm.Data = data;
        DataContext = vm;

    }
}

public enum OperatingStatus
{
    Working = 0,
    Broken = 1,
    Unknown = 2
}

public enum Make
{
    Ford,
    Honda,
    GM,
    Toyota
}

public class Column
{
    public Make Make { get; set; }
    public OperatingStatus OperatingStatus { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Column>>  Data { get; set; }

    public DataView MyDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            var rows = Data.Count();
            var cols = Data.First().Count();
            var t = new DataTable();
            for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString()));
            }

            foreach (var row in Data)
            {
                var newRow = t.NewRow();
                int c = 0;
                foreach (var col in row)                 
                {
                    newRow[c] = col.Make;
                    c++;
                }
                t.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return t.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}

public class NameToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;
        switch (input)
        {
            case "Ford":
                return Brushes.LightGreen;
            case "GM":
                return Brushes.Red;
            case "Toyota":
                return Brushes.Blue;
            case "Honda":
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            default:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NameToBrushConverter x:Key="NameToBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid Width="1000"
                  Margin="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"                   
                  DataContext="{Binding}"                      
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}"      >

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Make}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Make, Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

After trying Nik's suggestion and replacing 'Make' with 'Row[0]' in two places, I got the following, which is progress because there is some colour! If there is more changes, I'll report back here.

[image]

I would have expected to get something where the Ford square is green, Honda is yellow, GM is red, and Toyota is blue.  Something more like below (please excuse my horrible markup skills).

[image]

Comment: Is Name constant whilst the other columns vary? Assuming the array even has variable dimensions(?)  Quite some time back I wrote something which dealt with objects which had some fixed columns and any number of variable ones. I used a viewmodel with the fixed columns defined as properties and an observabledictionary for the columns. Not at all sure this would be good for what you're doing or in any way better than Nik's suggestion though. An expandoobject is another option.

Comment: Andy, I'm not sure I understand your question.  Each column has represents an object that has two properties "Make" and "OperatingStatus". BUT, for now I'm asking to just set the color based on Make.  Each row would have the same number of columns.  It needs to be configurable so that I can change the number of columns but this wouldn't happen within one run (app would have to restart).  Also, in the real app the data is more like 5000 rows and 15 columns.  But again, each column represents the same type of object.  Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the unfortunate side effect of using a `DataView` as your ItemsSource. The DataContext of a `DataGridRow` in this case is a `DataRowView` which has a property `Row`. This property contains an array of values which are the individual cells. `DataGridCell` inherits that `DataContext`. Then what you're looking for is `Row[0]` for the first column, `Row[1]` for your second column and so on. Using the XAML below for the `DataGridTextColumn`, produced the result you're looking for in my testing, where I used `Row[0]` instead of `Make` in the bindings. And thank you for providing such good working code, such a time saver!

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Row[0]}">
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Row[0], Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I recently needed to do something similar where my input had to be a 2-D array of indeterminate dimensions. I ended up making a reusable Custom Control extending a `DataGrid`. This control managed its own DataContext (a `DataTable`), which made the UI nice a clean without the need to use indices or any code-behind.

There may be a nicer way to do this, but I could not figure it out. Plus it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If your columns are known at design time, I would consider creating an ObservableCollection containing objects. If not, maybe someone has a better trick, but at least this should get your code working.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you perhaps post your full XAML and code, I did get some color but not what I was expecting.  I'll post the picture in my original, but basically I got 3 columns (instead of expected 2) and the first column had color.  Were the only changes you made, changing "Make" to "Row[0]" in two places?  Thanks for looking!

Comment: I'll definitely look at that further. In the Mean time, what do you expect to see? A couple things to look at: You will need to set "AutoGenerateColumns" to false on the DataGrid. You will also need to define each column in XAML as you did for the "Make" Column. Lastly, you can set the column Headers in your DataView Object so that they are not blank or "0", "1", etc. That should give you a starting point. I'll post more tonight if still needed.

Comment: Nik, I added a very rough image showing what I'd expect. I would rather not have to define each and every column.  Here there are 2, but there could b 15.  They are all exactly the same. Isn't there some way to have a template or similar?  However, if necessary, I guess I could do that.   By all means, any ideas are appreciated.  And again, I'm not wedded to using a DataTable or DataView.  That's just what was used in the reference I mentioned.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I can already see a potential problem.  Note that each cell can be a different color.  That is, row 0, col 1 is yellow, but row 1, col 1 is blue.  I think I need to bind at the cell level,  not column level?

Comment: Ok, I see. There are definitely solutions. I don't have time right now to flesh it out, but I will later today.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out? I would have likely done something similar, not sure I can help you much further here, as it looks like you have the right idea, it will just need a little more flesh!

Comment: Thanks Nik, I think I have it figured out.  I did ask a minor question based on my code in case you're interested:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888969/how-to-display-particular-property-of-collection-in-datagrid-cells-wpf?noredirect=1#comment86801408_49888969

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for posterity. I don't claim it's the best or most elegant and would welcome alternative ideas. In particular, the whole idea of having to expose a DataView rather than just `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Column>>` seems crazy.

In additions to the articles I initially mentioned, I also found the following extremely useful:

https://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/the-wpf-datagrid-and-me/
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3cbe382-99b0-4005-8cb9-cd2f36e74ed3/how-to-change-a-datagrid-cells-background-color-using-a-converter?forum=wpf

CODE

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

        List<Column> row1 = new List<Column>()
        {
            new Column(){Make = Make.Ford,OperatingStatus =  OperatingStatus.Broken},
            new Column(){Make = Make.Honda, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Unknown}
        };
        List<Column> row2 = new List<Column>()
        {
            new Column() {Make = Make.GM, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Working},
            new Column() {Make = Make.Toyota, OperatingStatus = OperatingStatus.Broken}
        };

        List<List<Column>> data = new List<List<Column>>();
        data.Add(row1);
        data.Add(row2);
        vm.Data = data;
        DataContext = vm;

    }
}

public enum OperatingStatus
{
    Working = 0,
    Broken = 1,
    Unknown = 2
}

public enum Make
{
    Ford,
    Honda,
    GM,
    Toyota
}

public class Column
{
    public Make Make { get; set; }
    public OperatingStatus OperatingStatus { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Column>>  Data { get; set; }

    public DataView MyDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            var rows = Data.Count();
            var cols = Data.First().Count();
            var t = new DataTable();
            for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString()));
                //t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString(),typeof(StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion.Column)));
            }

            foreach (var row in Data)
            {
                var newRow = t.NewRow();
                int c = 0;
                foreach (var col in row)
                {
                    newRow[c] = col.Make;
                    c++;
                }
                t.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return t.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}



public class ConverterHoldoffGridColor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[1] is DataRow)
        {
            var cell = (DataGridCell) values[0];
            var row = (DataRow) values[1];
            var columnName = cell.Column.SortMemberPath;
            string input = (row[columnName] as string);
            //string input = (row[columnName] as StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion.Column).Make.ToString();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "Ford":
                    return Brushes.LightGreen;
                case "GM":
                    return Brushes.Red;
                case "Toyota":
                    return Brushes.Blue;
                case "Honda":
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                default:
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
        }
        
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowDataGridQuestion"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    
    <local:ConverterHoldoffGridColor x:Key="bgHoldoffGridColor" />
    <Style x:Key="CellHighlighterStyle">

       
        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding
                Converter="{StaticResource bgHoldoffGridColor}" >
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="Row" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

       
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellHighlighterStyle}" 
            DataContext="{Binding }"                      
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">

           
        </DataGrid>
        
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```