# Dynamically create a grid of pictureboxs

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a set of arrays in an array that contain characters e.g.
{{'#','.','#'}{'#','$','#'}{'#','@','#',}{'#','#','#',}}
And what I want to be able to create a grid based on the number of those dynamically as the amount can change (they will always have the same amount of characters in every internal array)
so i want the internal arrays to be rows and the characters inside to each be on their own column so it would look like

"#.#"
"#$#"
"#@#"
"###"

so what would be the best way to setup this grid and then what i would like to do is fill all of those cells with pictureboxs as depending on what symbol it is it will be a specific picture.

so just wondering what the best way to do this would be any help/advice is much appreciated

Comment: Using a `DataGridView` is the most simple option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a WPF grid based on a 2-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DataGridView` is the most simple option. For example:

```
var images = new Dictionary<char, Image>()
{
    {'#', Properties.Resources.Image1},
    {'.', Properties.Resources.Image2},
    {'$', Properties.Resources.Image3},
    {'@', Properties.Resources.Image4},
};
var data = new List<string>() { "#.#", "#$#", "#@#", "###" };
var list = data.Select(x => new
                       {
                           A = images[x[0]],
                           B = images[x[1]],
                           C = images[x[2]]
                       }).ToList();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

In above code, I created a dictionary for mapping between characters and images. Then shaped input data to a list containing that images instead of characters. When you set the result list as `DataSource` of `DataGridView` you will see those  images instead of characters.

---

If for any reason you don't want to use anonymous object, you can simply create a dynamic `DataTable` having any number of columns:

```
var images = new Dictionary<char, Image>()
{
    {'#', Properties.Resources.Image1},
    {'.', Properties.Resources.Image2},
    {'$', Properties.Resources.Image3},
    {'@', Properties.Resources.Image4},
};
char[][] data = new char[][]{ 
    new char[] {'#','.','#'},
    new char[] {'#','$','#'},
    new char[] {'#','@','#'},
    new char[] {'#','#','#'},
};
var dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Max(x => x.Count()); i++)
    dt.Columns.Add(string.Format("C{0}", i), typeof(Image));
data.ToList().ForEach(a => dt.Rows.Add(a.Select(x=>images[x]).ToArray()));
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: This works really well thanks i had to do a bit of adapting but thanks so much the only problem though is it creates a row of white boxes with red "X"s at the bottom of it so I think its in that second to bottom line where it is creating 1 to many rows and therefor doesnt have anything to put in the cells but ill figure it out tomorrow

Comment: You'r welcome. Set `this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;`.